# Insert Excel data to SQL server using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I wrote simple application to upload excel data to sql. I am using ADO.NET and OLEDB. So I have one table so far on sql server which contains only two fields ProbeID (which is auto generated) and ProbeName(this I am retrieving from my xls file). My excel file contains bunch of columns but I need only Probe Name. So when app reads the file and store to oledb it seems that Name fields is always stays null and when it inserts to db table it inserts the right amount of rows  but with the null ProbeName value. I can't figure it out where is the issue in my code. Here is my Upload method. What am I doing wrong?

```
 [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult UploadExcel(Probe probes, HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
    {

        var data = new List<string>();
        if (FileUpload != null)
        {
            // tdata.ExecuteCommand("truncate table OtherCompanyAssets");  
            if (FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {


                var filename = FileUpload.FileName;
                var targetpath = Server.MapPath("~/Doc/");
                FileUpload.SaveAs(targetpath + filename);
                var pathToExcelFile = targetpath + filename;
                var connectionString = "";
                if (filename.EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", pathToExcelFile);
                }
                else if (filename.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", pathToExcelFile);
                }

                var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [report$]", connectionString);
                var ds = new DataSet();

                adapter.Fill(ds, "ExcelTable");

                var dtable = ds.Tables["ExcelTable"];

                const string sheetName = "report";

                var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathToExcelFile);
                var dataInProbe = from a in excelFile.Worksheet<Probe>(sheetName) select a;

                foreach (var a in dataInProbe)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (a.ProbeName != "")
                        {
                            var pr = new Probe();
                            pr.ProbeName = a.ProbeName;
                            db.Probes.Add(pr);

                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data.Add("<ul>");
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.ProbeName)) data.Add("<li> Probe name is required</li>");
                            data.Add("</ul>");
                            data.ToArray();
                            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                        }
                    }

                    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                    {
                        foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                        {

                            foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                            {

                                Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                //deleting excel file from folder  
                if ((System.IO.File.Exists(pathToExcelFile)))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(pathToExcelFile);
                }
                return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                //alert message for invalid file format  
                data.Add("<ul>");
                data.Add("<li>Only Excel file format is allowed</li>");
                data.Add("</ul>");
                data.ToArray();
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            data.Add("<ul>");
            if (FileUpload == null) data.Add("<li>Please choose Excel file</li>");
            data.Add("</ul>");
            data.ToArray();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use Import Export wizard to import data from excell to SQL SERVER. Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use the ASP.NET MVC because later on I need to create UI where user after insertion can see the inserted data.

Comment: You tagged sql - server. So in sql we can do it in this way and that file we can schedule it in SQL Job.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to figure it out but I made it work, this just the trial app for upload excel file to db, but for the future I think it is easier to use EF instead of dataset.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadExcel(Probe probes, HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
    {

        var data = new List<string>();
        if (FileUpload != null)
        {  
            if (FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                var filename = FileUpload.FileName;
                var targetpath = Server.MapPath("~/Doc/");
                FileUpload.SaveAs(targetpath + filename);
                var pathToExcelFile = targetpath + filename;
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName);
                string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload.FileName);
                DataTable dataFound = Import_To_Grid(pathToExcelFile, Extension, "Yes");
                List<ProbeData> dataProbList = new List<ProbeData>();
                foreach (DataRow item in dataFound.Rows)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var probeName = item["Probe"].ToString();
                        var alreadyexist = db.Probes.Where(d => d.ProbeName == probeName).FirstOrDefault();
                        var probId = 0;
                        if (alreadyexist != null)
                        {
                            probId = alreadyexist.Probe_ID;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Probe objProb = new Probe();
                            objProb.ProbeName = probeName.ToString();
                            db.Probes.Add(objProb);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            probId = objProb.Probe_ID;
                            ProbeData objPD = new ProbeData();
                            objPD.ProbeId = probId;
                            objPD.ProbeName = objProb.ProbeName;
                            dataProbList.Add(objPD);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                    {
                        foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                        {

                            foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                            {

                                Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);

                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
                //deleting excel file from folder  
                if ((System.IO.File.Exists(pathToExcelFile)))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(pathToExcelFile);
                }
                ViewBag.ProbeData = dataProbList;
                //ViewBag.SCImportData = dataSCImporobList;
                return View("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                //alert message for invalid file format  
                data.Add("<ul>");
                data.Add("<li>Only Excel file format is allowed</li>");
                data.Add("</ul>");
                data.ToArray();
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            data.Add("<ul>");
            if (FileUpload == null) data.Add("<li>Please choose Excel file</li>");
            data.Add("</ul>");
            data.ToArray();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    private DataTable Import_To_Grid(string FilePath, string Extension, string isHDR)
    {
        string conStr = "";
        switch (Extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"]
                         .ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"]
                          .ConnectionString;
                break;
        }
        conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
        OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

        //Get the name of First Sheet
        connExcel.Open();
        DataTable dtExcelSchema;
        dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        connExcel.Close();

        //Read Data from First Sheet
        connExcel.Open();
        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
        oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        oda.Fill(dt);
        connExcel.Close();
        return dt;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SqlBulkCopy class as the name suggests does bulk insert from one source to another and hence all rows from the Excel sheet can be easily read and inserted into SQL Server database table using the SqlBulkCopy class.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Import-data-from-Excel-file-to-SQL-Server-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx